# Los campos de un formulario que no se completan se guarden como NULL en la base de datos o que se ignoren en la consulta

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Yo tengo un formulario con distintos inputs, de los cuales la gran mayoría no son necesarios de llenar (y algunos de estos son inputs que se relacionan con otras tablas), mi duda es, cuando dichos inputs quedan vacios, ¿Como hago que no se agreguen en el insert a la base de datos o para que se inserten pero con valor null?

Los inputs de tipo "text" que están en el insert/update y que en la tabla son de tipo varchar no tiran error porque se almacenan como tipo NULL, sin embargo todos los demás (checkbox, select o inputs que tienen que enviar numeros) no, tiran error a la hora de ejecutar la consulta, intente dejandoles el value = "" pero igual no funciona.

Tendria que hacer algun chequeo previo en el controlador o es algo que se tiene que configurar en la misma base de datos?

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente especifico, gracias!

Comment: ojo...aunque mande numeros los checkbox, select etc.. lo recibes como string! Si tienes en la base de datos configurado como (int) te arroja error si no conviertes el valor de string a int antes

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que se encarga de guardar los datos?

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien el problema, lo que quieres hacer es almacenar algunos valores en `null` cuando están vacíos en el formulario o cuando tienen determinado valor.

Laravel 5.4 incluye un middleware que se encarga de convertir las cadenas vacías del request a `null`.

```
<?php
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware;
class ConvertEmptyStringsToNull extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

---

Por otra parte, no necesitas escribir el valor `null` en la base de datos, simplemente agregas el modificador *nullable* a los campos que lo necesiten, así lo puedes definir en la migración, y su valor por defecto será `null`.

Un ejemplo tomado de la documentación:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email')->nullable();
});
```

Más información: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner un valor que no vayas a usar nunca, por ejemplo `value="-1"`

y en tu código del post de php poner algo como

```
if($_POST['nameDeTuInput'] == '-1') {
  $valor = NULL;
}
```

y luego almacenas valor en la consulta de insert, u otra opción si no se va a usar ponerlo como `disabled` en el html mediante un checkbox, entonces no se enviará por el método POST y y puedes usar

```
if(isset($_POST['nameDeTuInput'])) {
  $valor = NULL;
}
```